# Restrict api key to specific functions in Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

I am using Serverless and have a service with two functions.
I have setup API Keys to restrict access to the service.

One function does a basic task
The 2nd function is activated at the end of the 1st function to return a more thorough result.

I would like all API Keys be to able to access the 1st function but only some API Keys to access the 2nd function kind of like a premium feature that is activated for some users.

The only solution I can think of that works is having two separate services but this seems like a waste of resources as I have to request one API from the other. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the usage plans associated with an API key and act on that information, see:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/usageplan-by-id/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/link-relation/apikey-usageplans

So instead of requiring a mere presence of an API key, you can inspect some properties associated with it and decide to either allow or disallow the usage of your function based on that, but you will have to implement that logic inside of a function for the biggest flexibility.

For more info see:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/api-key/

especially links pointing to info on plans and marketplace.